# Can git push.default overwrite "dst"?

Tags: git, git-push

`push.default` Defines the action `git push` should take if no refspec is explicitly given. But is there a situation in which using one of it's possible value cause `non-fast-forward  update` and overwriting the "dst" of push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`push.default` will not change the behavior in case of non-fast forward. Non-fast forward push are only done when `--force` is used, or when a `+` is prepended to the refspec being pushed.